# Magento 2: Percent coupon with discount amount limit

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, coupon

I want to give customers a 10% discount coupon but I want to enforce a discount amount limit, that is that the maximum discount amount is $250. Is there a way to limit this using a coupon?